Flask error: Exception: Missing user_loader or request_loader
I'm getting the exception error when I run my application even though it's definitely inside my code.
This is my code, which contains the necessary user loader.
website/models.py_________
from website import db, login_manager
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from website import login

# **@login_manager.user_loader
# def load_user(user_id):
# return User.query.get(user_id)
# **
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)

    profile_image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False, default = 'default.png')
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __init__(self, email, username, password):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password): 
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
 
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User {self.username}"

website/init.py_____________________

import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)

#database
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
#
# **
# login_manager = LoginManager()
# login_manager.init_app(app)
# login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'**



#Blueprints
from website.core.views import core
from website.error_pages.handlers import error_pages



app.register_blueprint(core, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(error_pages)


What is the cause of this error, and what can I do to solve this? Thanks!

what is the full error ?
